# MySQL sql statement fails to retrieve data

Tags: php, mysql

The following example fails to produce any results.

```
$cxr_sql=mysql_query("select username from game g join user u
                      on g.cxrId = u.id
                      where g.ticket='" . $gameTicket . "'");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($cxr_sql);
$cxr=$row['username'];
```

However, this (same code) works on an other system. And the sql produce the expected result when executed in mysqlworkbench on the system that fails.
So why is it suddently empty when executed from PHP.

Driving me f23423 insane!!!

PS. i have echo'ed the sql statement to the screen. It performs fine in workbench????

Comment: Does mysql_error() report anything?  Are you sure the database name and connection details are the same?

Comment: You're probably connecting to the wrong database from your PHP code. This is an extremely common error, especially if you are switching to a new host.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing either

```
$row=mysql_fetch_array($cxr_sql, MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

or

```
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($cxr_sql);
```

I know mysql_fetch_array is suppose to default to both.. but maybe something weird is going  on

If this doesnt work try doing

```
echo mysql_error();
```

after the query

Comment: echo mysql_error(); shows "No database selected"
But i have selected the database.
It is clearly a migration issue. But i still have no f'ing clue.

Comment: Check to make sure the user you are connecting to the database with exists, and that the password is right, and that the user has permission to access that database

Comment: you may not have included config file where you are using connection

Comment: Kris: It was a permission related issue on the new server.
Thanks